# what is the operator name that for positive value returns the same and for negatvie returns zero?

Tags: reference-request, operator-theory

there is an operator that currently I see in mechanical engineering topics that for positive values returns the same quantity inside, and for negative values, returns zero , it's like <> but a bit taller , sorry that the keyboard doesn't have it

Comment: Is it $\langle x \rangle$? $\leftarrow$ is \langle and \rangle in TeX, don't know the operator name though. Also try drawing your symbol here: http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html

Comment: yes I think , it's not specific to TeX , it's a specific mathematical operator, like sign function , that I am searching for its name

Comment: I was going to say, there's a function called the Heaviside function $\Theta$, and if you had a function $f(x)$, and wanted the values to vanish for negative numbers, you can multiply $\Theta(x)\cdot f(x)$. The Heaviside function $\Theta(x-a)=\begin{cases} 1 \quad \text{if } x\geq a \\ 0 \quad \text{if } x<a \end{cases}$

Comment: It's called ramp function/positive part: $x^+=\max(x,0)$.

Comment: Apparently the notation itself has a wikipedia page: [Macaulay brackets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Macaulay_brackets).

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about a **name** attached to that, but the function
$$
\frac12\left(x+|x|\right)
$$
does exactly what you require.